# Using JQuery to rotate an image to and forth a degree

Tags: jquery, rotation

I have been searching Stackoverflow and cannot find the answer to my question anywhere. I am trying to make a search light effect which is coming appearing from behind buildings, like the one on [this site](http://gtav.net). I have made a start, [here](http://ilobby.co.uk/beta). I understand that the website which contains the animated spotlights (in the top right) are using two pieces of javascript:

sunset2.js & .../jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

I have also noticed that in the code of the sunset.js file that it was made by Wilq32 in 2009.
I then went to the site: code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/ and realized that the owner of the other site (one that contains the spotlights) had used that to create the spotlight effect.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is

```
TypeError: $beacon.delay is not a function
```

It is because you are using older version of jquery, So use the latest one i.e.

Replace this script reference

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This will fix your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for the immediate response! You have solved my error!